# Artifactory admin credentials reset

Tags: artifactory

I am stuck due to lost admin user credential in my artifactory setup.

tried steps listed at

https://www.mail-archive.com/artifactory-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01929.html

http://forums.jfrog.org/Lost-admin-password-td5435810.html

but still no succcess.
Log says:

```
[http-bio-8081-exec-3] [ERROR] (o.a.w.DefaultExceptionMapper:105) - Connection lost, give up responding.
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ResponseIOException: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebResponse.flush(ServletWebResponse.java:255) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.wicket.application.HeaderBufferingWebResponse.flush(HeaderBufferingWebResponse.java:89) ~[artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.wicket.application.IgnoreEofWebResponse.flush(IgnoreEofWebResponse.java:105) ~[artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.AbstractResource.setResponseHeaders(AbstractResource.java:611) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.AbstractResource.respond(AbstractResource.java:485) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.resource.ResourceRequestHandler.respond(ResourceRequestHandler.java:77) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.resource.ResourceReferenceRequestHandler.respond(ResourceReferenceRequestHandler.java:105) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:750) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) ~[wicket-request-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:252) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:209) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:280) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:162) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:218) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:166) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:85) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:272) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:181) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:143) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:57) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:72) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_15]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:364) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:326) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:571) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:307) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:161) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebResponse.flush(ServletWebResponse.java:251) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:790) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:359) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
2013-12-11 15:15:50,760 [http-bio-8081-exec-2] [ERROR] (o.a.w.DefaultExceptionMapper:105) - Connection lost, give up responding.
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ResponseIOException: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebResponse.flush(ServletWebResponse.java:255) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.wicket.application.HeaderBufferingWebResponse.flush(HeaderBufferingWebResponse.java:89) ~[artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.wicket.application.IgnoreEofWebResponse.flush(IgnoreEofWebResponse.java:105) ~[artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.AbstractResource.setResponseHeaders(AbstractResource.java:611) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.AbstractResource.respond(AbstractResource.java:485) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.resource.ResourceRequestHandler.respond(ResourceRequestHandler.java:77) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.resource.ResourceReferenceRequestHandler.respond(ResourceReferenceRequestHandler.java:105) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:750) ~[wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) ~[wicket-request-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:252) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:209) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:280) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:162) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:218) [wicket-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:166) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:85) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:272) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:181) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:143) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:57) [artifactory-web-application-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both resources you mention are correct, but outdated. The official documentation has [a very detailed section of restoring the default admin password](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Users#ManagingUsers-RecreatingtheDefaultAdminUser).

The exception in log has nothing to do with authentication/authorization, though.

Comment: Thansk , i gotta that .

Comment: Briefly:
Create a file called bootstrap.creds under JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/access with this content:
admin1@*=password1

$ chmod 600 bootstrap.creds
$ chown artifactory:artifactory bootstrap.creds

And restart app